# Is it possible to optimize this ms sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query is small but slows my Access FrontEnd/ SQL BackEnd application to a halt.
Is there a way to optimize it?

From what I can understand it displays the CID and the WeekNr of the last CultureStepID.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Culture.CID,
(SELECT TOP (1) WeekNr
FROM CultureStep
WHERE (CultureID = Culture.CID)
ORDER BY CultureStepID) AS normalstartweek

FROM Culture
INNER JOIN CultureStep ON Culture.CID= CultureStep.CID
```

Edit:

Number of Rows for Query: 2309

CultureStep Table: 13961

Culture Table: 2472

[image]

Comment: Why use INNER JOIN with CultureStep table if you take the info by subquery?

Comment: DIstinct means you run a temdb nightmare. Please post the query plan and rework the query in a way to avoid distinct. We also would love to know the number of rows in each table.

Comment: Culture.CID is associated to CultureStep.CultureID (subquery) and CultureStep.CID (join condition). Is this a mistake? if it is not, could you explain this?

Comment: Note that the "ORDER BY" defaults to an ascending order: the CultureStep with the smallest CultureStepID value will be selected by the subquery (which you referred to as "the last CultureStepId").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

First solution (you show all Culture indipendent by existence of CultureStep):

```
SELECT Culture.CID,
(SELECT CS.WeekNr
FROM CultureStep CS
WHERE (CS.CultureID = Culture.CID)
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'NEXT'
    FROM CultureStep CS2
    WHERE CS2.CultureID = CS.CultureID
    AND CS2.CultureStepID > CS.CultureStepID)
) AS normalstartweek
FROM Culture
```

Second solution: (you show all Culture if exists linked CultureStep):

```
SELECT Culture.CID,
(SELECT CS.WeekNr
FROM CultureStep CS
WHERE (CS.CultureID = Culture.CID)
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'NEXT'
    FROM CultureStep CS2
    WHERE CS2.CultureID = CS.CultureID
    AND CS2.CultureStepID > CS.CultureStepID)
) AS normalstartweek
FROM Culture
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'CultureStep'
    FROM CultureStep
    WHERE (CultureID = Culture.CID)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Culture.CID,
(SELECT TOP (1) WeekNr
FROM CultureStep
WHERE (CultureID = Culture.CID)
ORDER BY CultureStepID) AS normalstartweek
FROM Culture
WHERE Exists(SELECT CID FROM CultureStep WHERE CultureStep.CID=Culture.CID)
```